# creating compiled library components from classes for Android project

Tags: android

I have some "data/helper classes" defined which I use in several projects. These data classes are quite big and really do not change between the projects. There is some logic in the data classes in their methods - this also remains the same among all the projects. These "data classes" are not activities!

Now when creating a new project that uses these "data classes" it needs to compile all their code everytime, since I always make a copy of these classes and paste it in the new projects. This slows down the development/compilation of new projects.

Is there an efficient way to "pre-compile" or somehow define these "data/helper classes" as library components so that development of new projects is more efficient and only compiles the new code just linking in these "data classes" somehow?

I only found a way to make activities into libraries - but this reusable classes are not activities.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common use case, You should move and create all your common stuff (data/helper classes) into a classic jar library, compiled and end up with a common-lib.jar, and add this common-lib.jar to either your main project or library project classpath.

Check out the official dev guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html) to see how to add external jar library to either Android project or Android library project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android Library type](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html) of project or you can attach a jar file to your library. If you want to make a dependency (i.e. if you want your library code to be updated in all end projects) you have to use building tools like Maven or Ant and configure them properly.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up exporting these classes into a jar and then adding this jar back (incl to the build path). I wonder if there is any difference to a Library Project? ps. I am nut sure In uderstand: "or you can attach a jar file to your library." Do you mean adding the jar to the project not to the a library?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Jar file should be attached to the project, not to the library. In Android Library project you can include Android components.